# How to run ASP.NET site with bundled files?

Tags: asp.net, bundle

I built ASP.NET code and run release mode in VS2015.
All JS and CSS is on the suitable folder of my project as you see the below green section.

[image]

So I need a bundled site as next red section. How can I do?

Comment: So you need the green highlighted style files to be bundled like the sample in the red highlighted image?

Comment: Yes.

I need to run sites with bundled JS and CSS files.

Comment: Is this an MVC site?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you know the terminology "bundling" but you weren't able find an answer with the most simple of Google searches?  Surely, you did research first, before asking here? https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: silencedmessage - that is exactly why I was asking ... I was really confused about the question since the answer was in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using the BundleConfig class, you can create Script and Style bundles.  When you publish, your bundled files will be minified.